# Using Cucumber.js with Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, bdd, jestjs, cucumberjs

I am using Jest for my unit tests and I'm in the process of integrating Cucumber.js for running specs written in Gherkin.

I have it all set up and it's working, but I am running into one problem: How can I use Jest's `expect`? I could use `chai`'s, but I'd like to keep the `expect` syntax the same between my unit tests and my step definitions (I don't want `to.equal` in my step definitions and `toEqual` in my unit tests).

How can I do that? After some digging it seems as if Jest relies on the `expect` npm package. I could depend on that package explicitly in my `package.json`, but I'd much rather use my existing Jest dependency. Maybe that's not possible, but I hope it is.

Another option would be to somehow execute the Gherkin specs with the Jest test-runner. I'd be open to that option as well. At the moment I'm running them by calling `cucumber.js` separately from my Jest test-runner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`expect` is a globally scoped during jest runtime. So as long as you are running jest it will be available.  I'm using this package (needs some config to transform correctly to your babel config): [gherkin-jest](https://github.com/stewartml/gherkin-jest)

Here's a feature using the [DOM-testing  example](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html#dom-testing) from the jest docs:

```
Feature: Using feature files in jest and cucumber
  As a developer
  I want to write tests in cucumber and jest
  So that businesspeople understand tests and I can test React

  Scenario: Emoji toggles upon checking and unchecking the checkbox
    Given I did not check the checkbox, so the label is ""
    When I check the box and the emoji toggles to be ""
```

```js
import {cucumber as c} from 'gherkin-jest'
import React from 'react'
import {mount} from 'enzyme'
import {Checkbox} from '../src/components'

c.defineCreateWorld(() => ({
  checkbox:null
}))

c.defineRule('I did not check the checkbox so the label is {string}', (world, off) => {
  world.checkbox = mount(<Checkbox labelOff={off} />)
  expect(world.checkbox.text()).toBe(off)
})


c.defineRule('I checked the box and the emoji toggles to be {string}', (world, on) =>{
  world.checkbox = mount(<Checkbox labelOn={on}/>)
  world.checkbox.find('TouchableOpacity').props().onPress()
  expect(world.checkbox.text()).toBe(on)
})
```

This [issue](https://github.com/stewartml/gherkin-jest/issues/6) I posted gives an example of the config.

Answer (score 14):

My `react-native` environment:

```
"cucumber": "^4.1.0",
"jest": "22.4.2",
```

In my `steps definition` file, I just require it like this

```
const { Given, Then, When } = require('cucumber');
const expect = require('expect');
```

Expect is part of Jest, so you can import it as its own object. Then I can use it wherever I need an assertion. Note: `newMember` is declared and populated elsewhere.

```
Given('Sara has provided account details', function() {
  for (const prop in newMember) {
    expect(newMember[prop]).toBeTruthy();
  }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Live example: https://testjam.io/?p=D11o5cwOIQukGy1F6GRU

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to use jest-cucumber

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-cucumber.

gives you the flexibility of using both frameworks

Comment: I would love to know what the advantages of using `jest-cucumber` over vanilla `cucumber.js`. It must be the ecosystem, but its not entirely obvious?